# REDUX: My array's objects has updated while adding new object to my array

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-persist

I am working on a project in React and I am using Redux. My reducer has 2 things: once is myCity object to hold city that comes from my API and an array. I get my object from API to myCity object. However, when I try to add new response object to my array, array's objects updated. I want to add this response as a new object to my array. What is the problem? How can I fix?

Here is my code:

```
import ActionTypes from "../constants/ActionTypes";

const initialState = {
  myCities: [],
  aCity: {},
};

export const WeatherReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case ActionTypes.GETBY_CITYNAME:
      let arr = initialState.myCities;
      return {
        ...state,
        aCity: payload,
        myCities: [...arr, payload],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

[image: my redux]

Comment: what's the type of payload string or an object ? also if you can provide the sample data or a console of state

Comment: Try to use myCities: [...state.myCities, payload],

Comment: @AyèchHamza not works

Comment: @pageNotfoUnd my response is an object. I dont understand if clause. I also try to manage in a state

Comment: show us the copy of state after updation

Comment: @pageNotfoUnd I added a photo.

Comment: [...state.myCities, payload] what happens on doing this ??? this should work if the payload is an object is will append an new object with the value from payload to the myCities array

Comment: @pageNotfoUnd idk why but now it works >:(  thank you for your effort. I appreciate